# Swift: Custom Cell isn't being detected when in view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, avplayer

What I'm trying to create is a Vine like video feed that autplay/pauses videos when the cell containing the video is in view. To contain the video I'm using a custom cell name `TVC` which has a xib attached for the design of the custom cell. At the moment I have the tableview loading the cells and the videos, however when I try to use `didEndDisplaying` and `willDisplay` to determine if the cell is in view to play/pause the video accordingly, it doesn't seem to detect if the cell is in view. Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> TVC {
   // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TVC", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TVC
    let vide = sweets[indexPath.row]



    let currentURL: URL = URL(string: vide.content)!
    print("final", currentURL)

    print(vide.content)
    print(vide.addedByUser)
    cell.label?.text = vide.addedByUser
   // performSegue(withIdentifier: "cell", sender: self)
    cell.moviePlayer(url: currentURL)


    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: TVC, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("out of display")
    cell.player.pause()


}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: TVC, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("playing")
    cell.player.play()

}
```

and my custom cell class

```
class TVC: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var videoContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var urlString: String!
var videoURL: URL!
var jacksURL: URL!
var url: String!
var player: AVPlayer!

@IBOutlet weak var VideoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()





    let radiusC: CGFloat = card.frame.width / 2.0
    let shadowPathC = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: 2 * radiusC, height: card.frame.height))

    let radius: CGFloat = videoContainer.frame.width / 2.0
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: 2 * radius, height: videoContainer.frame.height))
    videoContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    videoContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    videoContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.8)
    videoContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    videoContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    videoContainer.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    videoContainer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    self.videoContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    VideoView.layer.masksToBounds =  true
    self.VideoView.layer.cornerRadius = 8


    card.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)
    card.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    card.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    card.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    card.layer.shadowPath = shadowPathC.cgPath
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 8




    let currentURL: URL = URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vaudiodatabasetest.appspot.com/o/myMovies%2F2017-02-20-01-01-47.mov?alt=media&token=a41389a1-2f1f-424b-b999-e7a0ca774e0c")!


   videoURL = currentURL as URL!

    moviePlayer(url: videoURL)



}





 func moviePlayer(url: URL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)


    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.VideoView.bounds
    self.VideoView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.VideoView?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.VideoView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    player.externalPlaybackVideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil)
    {
        notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
        player.seek(to: t1)
        player.play()
    }


}



}
```

Comment: What does `doesn't seem to detect if the cell is in view` mean? Are the methods being called? Also, why are you not using `dequeueReusableCell`? Without dequeuing a cell I am not sure the `willDisplayCell` and `didEndDisplayingCell` methods will be called. Please clarify the exact problem that is occurring.

Comment: @RoboticCat what is dequeReusableCell? How do I use it?

Comment: @RoboticCat I just realised what you meant, and I was taught not to use deque when trying to load custom cells

Comment: You should always use the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)` method - you've been given some bad advice. Your custom cell may need some re-work so that you do not add multiple observers (one is added each time you call your `moviePlayer` method). You also want to remove the observer in the cell's `deinit`.

Comment: @RoboticCat could you expand on that with reference to my code? I'm just starting Swift, so I'm a complete beginner.